# Android Robotium waitForActivity not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to wait for a splash screen to finish before playing with the main screen.  I cannot get waitForActivity to work.  Any suggestions?

```
public class InputLeadTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SplashActivity> {

private Solo solo;

public InputLeadTest() {
    super(SplashActivity.class);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
}

public void testPreferenceIsSaved() throws Exception {
    solo.unlockScreen();
    solo.waitForActivity("MainActivity", 10000);
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected MainActivity activity", "MainActivity"); 
}
}
```

I've tried wait, waitForActivity(String), waitForActivity(String, int), waitForView.  None are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never answered my own question before, but maybe this will save someone an hour of time (thats how long it took me :-/ )

```
    solo.unlockScreen();
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected SplashActivity activity", "SplashActivity"); 
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation());
    solo.waitForActivity("MainActivity");
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected MainActivity activity", "MainActivity");
```

Had to create a new solo object.

Answer (score 0):

This API is used in this way, like if you are having two activities in you application activity1 and activity2. And you test case is like do something on activity1 and wait for activity2 because of operation on activity1 and then do something on activity2. In that case you can use this solo.waitForActivity("activity2").

As we usually don't do any operation on splash screen, best way to handle your case is to create new object of solo with MainActivity.